# Prove there exists a member of a sequence that's less than the average.

Tags: discrete-mathematics, proof-verification, proof-writing

I'm looking for verification of my proof.

> Suppose $\exists \ i,j \ $ such that $s_i \neq s_j$. Prove $\exists \ k \ $ such that $s_k < A$
>
> Here $A = \frac{s_1+s_2+ ... + s_n}{n}$ is the average of the sequence.

Proof:

Assume, for contradiction, $\neg \ \exists \ k (s_k < A)$. That is, assume $\forall \ k(s_k \geq A)$. But, since the hypothesis says that not all members of the sequence are equal, then we can't have $\forall \ k(s_k = A)$. So we must only consider the case where $\forall \ k(s_k > A)$.

By assumption:

$s_1 > A$

$s_2 > A$

...

$s_n > A$

Adding these inequalities, we get: $s_1+s_2+...+s_n > nA$. Dividing by n, we get $\frac{s_1+s_2+ ... + s_n}{n} > A$. This contradicts the definition of A. Therefore, we've proven by contradiction that $\exists \ k \ $ such that $s_k < A$. $\square$

Comment: It is not true that $\forall k(s_k\geq A)$ and $\neg\forall k(s_k=A)$ imply $\forall k(s_k>A)$. They imply $\exists k(s_k>A)$. Thus, one of the inequalities in your list is strictly not equal, so the sum is strictly greater than $nA$, from which the proof follows.

Comment: Proposition is false if n = 1.